# Can the local scope property and the passed in attribute value be used interchangeably in angularjs directives with isolate scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, isolated-scope

I'm following  [Dan Wahlin isolate scope with function parameters](https://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-3-isolate-scope-and-function-parameters). I have a couple of ambiguity in this article. Since there is no response at that site, I opted for stack overflow. I'm new to the javascript/angular world, response in detail is greatly welcomed.

1. When I use `datasource`, the code executes well. But according to the article, if I use `customers` then I get the exception cannot read property push of undefined.
2. When I see the scope in chrome with the custom directive selected, I cannot see the `datasource` and the `add`, instead I see the `customers` and `addCustomer`. Why is `datasource` and `add` not available in the isolated scope?. If I see the childscope, then i can see the `datasource` and the `add` in the isolate bindings. What does this mean?
3. Can the controller(defined inside the directive) scope access the isolate scope? How?
4. How to use `controllerAs` in the directive controller.

Here is the source code.

```
var app=angular.module('customermodule', []);
app.controller('CustomersController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
var counter = 0;
$scope.customer = {
    name: 'David',
    street: '1234 Anywhere St.'
};
$scope.customers = [];
$scope.addCustomer = function (name) {
    counter++;
    $scope.customers.push({
        name: (name) ? name : 'New Customer' + counter,
        street: counter + ' Cedar Point St.'
    });
};
$scope.changeData = function () {
    counter++;
    $scope.customer = {
        name: 'James',
        street: counter + ' Cedar Point St.'
    };
};
}]);
```

```js
app.directive('isolatedScopeWithController', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
        datasource: '=',
        add: '&',
    },
    controller: function ($scope) {
        $scope.addCustomer = function () {
        //Call external scope's function
        var name = 'New Customer Added by Directive';
        $scope.add({ name: name });

        //I get exception here if i use customers here. Instead If I use datasource, it works well.
        $scope.customers.push({
            name: name
        });
    };
},
    template: '<button ng-click="addCustomer()">Add Customer</button> 
<ul>' +
        '<li ng-repeat="cust in customers">{{ cust.name }}</li></ul>'
  };
 });
```

I want to know if I'm missing out anything in this case or the article is unintendedly mistake.

Comment: Add a `console.log($scope)` in the controller of isolate scope directive. It will log the isolate scope. The $scope injected to that controller *is* the isolate scope of that directive.

Comment: Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. It makes it hard to write a specific answer.